# .NET MAUI TapGesture Command not working in CollectionView

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

I have a CollectionView desing:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Days}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDay}">
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <GridItemsLayout 
               Orientation="Vertical"
                VerticalItemSpacing="5"
                Span="7" />
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModels:CalendarEntries">
            <Grid>
                <Label 
                    Text="{Binding Day}" Padding="0"
                    TextColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                    FontSize="17"
                    FontFamily="MagistralC"/>
                <customControls:CircularProgressBar
                   Progress="{Binding Progress}"
                   ProgressColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
                   ProgressLeftColor="LightGray"
                   Size="40"
                   TextColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
                   Thickness="4">
                    <customControls:CircularProgressBar.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger
                            TargetType="customControls:CircularProgressBar"
                            Binding="{Binding Progress}"
                            Value="0">
                            <Setter 
                                 Property="IsVisible" Value="false"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </customControls:CircularProgressBar.Triggers>
                </customControls:CircularProgressBar>
                <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer 
                        Command="{Binding ShowProgressDetailsCommand , Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:StatisticsViewModel}}}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
                        
                    </TapGestureRecognizer>
                </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

In the viewModel there is a command and I'm following the MVVM pattern and used commands and command properties in other views( but not in a collectionView with TapGesture). Is there a problem with CollectionView?

**Update** : When I press on specific pixel outside the label and circle progress bar It actually hits command breakpoint in the viewModel. What can be the problem?

Comment: I believe the tap gesture is also used by CollectionView to manage the selection of the item also, is it working better if you disable the selection for test `SelectionMode="None"`?

Comment: @Cfun no it's the same. Nothing's changed

Comment: any reason why the simple SelectionChanged event is not being used?

Comment: What platform are you running on? Gestures are quite broken on Android (but not sure whether in general or only for certain controls)

Comment: As @Cfun mentioned, Selection and Tap might interfere. In Addition to setting SelectionMode to None, try to delete the SelectedItem-Binding in your CollectionView and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal change events and tap gestures are not the same thing. Not firing every time is the obvious part of the difference. The not so obvious part for changes, is that some of them do not consider changes from "null" to something as a change. And plain and simple do not fire. Forcing you to pre-set them to useless as "apples = -1", so you can get the notification, when it is set for the first time.

Comment: Well, a extra line of code as compared to a bunch of handstands is often a wise solution. And who's suggesting they are the same thing? Certainly not me! As noted, this is about practial soltuions, and if the issue is being able to click again on a already selected row, then setting the item = null often is not only a great solution, but is much less hassle and efforts on the developer part - that's really the point. We don't know  why the index changed event not a option, and with that information, then we can actually make a wise and valid suggesting here, including use of the changed event.